# How to extract the contents in a txt file and then loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a `fruit.txt` file.
Just like this:

```
1.
"No": Apple
price<-c(92, 79, 51)
shop.location<- c(5, 3, 2)
visit.freq<-c(28, 20, 16)

2.
"No": Pear
price<-c(56, 44, 14)
shop.location<- c(4, 5, 6)
visit.freq<-c(24, 67, 23)

3.......
```

There are 200 such blocks in the `fruit.txt` file.

I have a another `value.R` code, it is just like this:

```
## Start


income <- price * visit.freq
compete <- price * shop.location * visit.freq
first.price <- price[1] 
c(first.price, income, compete)
## End
```

For each block in the `fruit.txt`, I need to put

```
price<-c(x, x, x, x, x)
shop.location<- c(x, x, x, x, x)
visit.freq<-c(x, x, x, x, x)
```

between the `start` and `income` in the `value.R` code. This will be a big task for me. So I wonder is there any convenient way to loop this process, thank you.

My expected result is:

```
 first.price income1 income2 income3 compete1 compete2 compete3
          92    2576    1580     816    12880     4740     1632  
          56    1344    2948     322     5376    14740     1932
           .....................................................
           x       x       x       x        x        x        x
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Will each block always have exactly 5 lines?  will there always be exactly 1 blank line between blocks?  If either answer is "no" then this becomes more complicated.

If the blocks all match above exactly (including the order) then I would suggest reading it in using the `readlines` function, then convert it to a matrix so that each "variable" is a row and each block is a column (or you could just use subsetting to grab each "variable").

Then you need a way to extract the information.  I would recommend against using `parse` and `eval`, even though they would work here, they can also be dangerous and produce hard to find bugs.

Instead I would use the `gsubfn` package and specifically the `strapply` function.  For example if the data is in a matrix of character strings then you can get all the prices like:

```
library(gsubfn)
myprices <- strapply(myblocks[3,], '[-0-9.]+', as.numeric)
```

then do the same thing with the other variables.  In this case the `myprices` variable will now be a list with each element being a vector of numbers.

You can then loop with something like:

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(myblocks)) ) {
  price <- myprices[[i]]
  ...
  income <- price * visit.freq
  ...
}
```

where the `...` is replaced with the additional code.

Remember that autoprinting does not happen inside of loops, so you will need to tell it to print your results.

or possibly use the `lapply` or `sapply` function instead of the loop if you want to save results (this will mean wrapping the above code into a function).

**Edit**

Since the simple approach will not work, we just need to be a little more creative.  You can still read all the data in using `readLines`, then use `grepl` to access one set of variables (as long as every block has exactly one row like each of the above, i.e. all have a row that assigns prices, but only 1 row.  Now to get the prices use:

```
w <- grepl('^price', myblocks)
myprices <- strapply(myblocks[w], '[-0-9.]+', as.numeric)
```

and the same idea again for the other lines.

Comment: Thank you. But actually not all the blocks contain 5 lines (some blocks has one or more annotation lines) and the number of blank lines can vary. Complicated.

Comment: @lightsnail, it is still doable, see my edit above for one approach.